# POST request not responding

Tags: excel, vba

As I mentioned in the title, I cannot get an answer.
Code that worked before.
What do you think, why is he not responding now?

When the macros run, no data appears on the screen and there is no error message.
What could be blocking the data flow?

```
Option Explicit
Sub Export_Table()

'Html Objects---------------------------------------'
 Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
 Dim htmlBody As MSHTML.htmlBody
 Dim ieTable As MSHTML.HTMLTable
 Dim Element As MSHTML.HTMLElementCollection


'Workbooks, Worksheets, Ranges, LastRow, Incrementers ----------------'
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim Table As Worksheet
 Dim i As Long

 Set wb = ThisWorkbook
 Set Table = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

 '-------------------------------------------'
 Dim xmlHttpRequest As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60  '
 '-------------------------------------------'


 i = 2

'Web Request --------------------------------------------------------------------------'
 With xmlHttpRequest
 .Open "POST", "https://www.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax", False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
.send "curr_id=951681&smlID=1695217&header=CLNX+Historical+Data&st_date=01%2F01%2F2021&end_date=03%2F01%2F2023&interval_sec=Monthly&sort_col=date&sort_ord=DESC&action=historical_data"


 If .Status = 200 Then

        Set htmlDoc = CreateHTMLDoc
        Set htmlBody = htmlDoc.body

        htmlBody.innerHTML = xmlHttpRequest.responseText

        Set ieTable = htmlDoc.getElementById("curr_table")

        For Each Element In ieTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            Table.Cells(i, 1) = Element.Children(0).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 2) = Element.Children(1).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 3) = Element.Children(2).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 4) = Element.Children(3).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 5) = Element.Children(4).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 6) = Element.Children(5).innerText
            Table.Cells(i, 7) = Element.Children(6).innerText

            i = i + 1
        DoEvents: Next Element
 End If
End With


Set xmlHttpRequest = Nothing
Set htmlDoc = Nothing
Set htmlBody = Nothing
Set ieTable = Nothing
Set Element = Nothing

End Sub

Public Function CreateHTMLDoc() As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set CreateHTMLDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
End Function
```

I thought it was a firewall issue.
I disabled it but the result is the same.

Comment: Add `Else : MsgBox .responseText` to the `If..EndIf` block

Comment: Microsoft Excel
It gives a long message under its title.

Comment: Microsoft Excel
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-US"> <head> <title>Just a moment...</title> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <meta
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> <meta
name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet"> </head> <body class="no-js"> <div class="main-wrapper" role="main"> <div class="main-content"> <noscript> <div id="challenge-error-title"> <div class="h2"> <span class="icon-wrapper"> <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div></span> <span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to

Comment: continue</span></div> </div> </noscript> </div> </div> <script> (funct ion(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvld: '2', cZone: "www.investing.com",cType: 'managed', cNounce: '12590', cRay: '81fd34f97bd21b09, cHash: '482d520d1f3157d', cUPMDTK:
"Vinstruments\/HistoricalDataAjax?_cf_chi_tk-bElyF7sNtL1XV4C4h.zl1Z
ROPZMA_Bc6yKSRVKfI7Ag-1698936805-0-gaNycGzNDJA, CFPWv:
'b',cTTimeMs: '1000'

Comment: the text says `Enable JavaScript and cookies to – continue` - maybe that is the problem, the site has changed.

Comment: The interesting thing is that these codes work on my friend's computer.